# History Timeline of free disk space on a windows system

Tags: windows, disk-space, history

What is a good and simple tool to monitor and graph free disk space over time on a windows machine?

The usual disk visualization tools are not a good fit, as the result should be an timeline of the free disk space. So this is not an duplicate...or is it?

Comment: As Joe Taylor said in your previous question: If you think it's not a duplicate, in the future please just **edit** it to make this clear, don't post a new question. I already edited your older question for you, which you can flag for moderator attention to have it reopened.